# How to select 2 pairs of distinct twins form a list of 4-tuples?

Tags: list-manipulation

Given a list of 4-tuples as follows.

```
data = Tuples[Range@6, 4];
```

I want to select any 4-tuples with two pairs of different twins, for example, as follows:

- `{1,2,1,2}`
- `{2,2,3,3}`
- `{4,5,5,4}`
- etc

## Attempt

First I select any association with length of 2 as follows

```
filter1 = Select[Counts /@ data, Length@# == 2 &]
```

Second I want to select only any association with value of 2. How to do this?

Comment: `data[[Flatten@Position[Sort /@ data, {x_, x_, y_, y_} /; x != y]]]` does work as well but too complicated.

Comment: As I love combinatorial approaches so the accepted answer must reflect it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `Permutations` *once* on `{1, 1, 2, 2}` to get a list of part indices and extract the associated `Part`s of each 2-subset of the base set:

```
positions = Permutations[{1, 1, 2, 2}];

pairs = Subsets[Range @ 6, {2}];
```

We can use `pairs` and `positions` with  `Outer` or `Distribute` or `Tuples`:

```
res1 = Join @@ Outer[Part, pairs, positions, 1];

res2 == Part @@@ Distribute[{pairs, positions}, List];

res3 = Distribute[{pairs, positions}, List, List, List, Part];

res4 = Part @@@ Tuples[{pairs, positions}];

res5 = Tuples[p[pairs, positions]] /. p -> Part;

res1 == res2 == res3 == res4 == res5
```

> ```
> True
> ```

You can also use [`Extract`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Extract.html) instead of `Part`:

```
res6 = Join @@ (Extract[#, List /@ positions] & /@ pairs);

res6 == res1
```

> ```
> True
> ```

```
res1
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Another way

```
Select[data, Values[Counts[#]] === {2, 2} &]
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
Pick[data, Values[Counts[#]] === {2, 2} & /@ data]
```

A pattern based approach:

```
Cases[
 data,
 {x_, x_, y_, y_} | {x_, y_, x_, y_} | {x_, y_, y_, x_} /; x != y
 ]
```

or

```
Select[
 data,
 MatchQ[Sort[#], {x_, x_, y_, y_} /; x != y] &
 ]
```

Comment: @WissenMachtFrei Fixed that now.

Comment: Thank you very much. As always, I am waiting for other answers (if any) before deciding the accepted answer.

Answer (score 5):

Another approach is to construct the desired tuples directly without selection from a larger set:

```
Subsets[Range@6, {2}] // 
 Map[Join[#, #] &] // 
 Map[Permutations] // 
 Flatten[#, 1] &
```

Answer (score 4):

Since the result of `Permutations[{i, i, j, j}]` is

```
    {{i, i, j, j}, {i, j, i, j}, {i, j, j, i}, {j, i, i, j}, {j, i, j, 
  i}, {j, j, i, i}}
```

We can use the method as below

```
Permutations[{#1, #1, #2, #2}] & @@@ Subsets[Range[6], {2}] // 
 Flatten[#, 1] &
```

Or

```
Permutations[{i, i, j, j}] /. Thread[{i, j} -> #] & /@ 
      Subsets[Range[6], {2}] // Flatten[#, 1] &
```

Or

```
Outer[#1 /. Thread[{i, j} -> #2] &, Permutations[{i, i, j, j}], 
      Subsets[Range[6], {2}], 1] // Flatten[#, 1] &
```

Answer (score 2):

```
data//Extract[#,Position[Tally/@#, {{_,2},{_,2}}]]&
```

> {{1, 1, 2, 2}, {1, 1, 3, 3}, {1, 1, 4, 4}, {1, 1, 5, 5}, {1, 1, 6, 6}, {1, 2, 1, 2}, {1, 2, 2, 1}, {1, 3, 1, 3}, {1, 3, 3, 1}, {1, 4, 1, 4}, {1, 4, 4, 1}, {1, 5, 1, 5}, {1, 5, 5, 1}, {1, 6, 1, 6}, {1, 6, 6, 1}, {2, 1, 1, 2}, {2, 1, 2, 1}, {2, 2, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 3, 3}, {2, 2, 4, 4}, {2, 2, 5, 5}, {2, 2, 6, 6}, {2, 3, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 3, 2}, {2, 4, 2, 4}, {2, 4, 4, 2}, {2, 5, 2, 5}, {2, 5, 5, 2}, {2, 6, 2, 6}, {2, 6, 6, 2}, {3, 1, 1, 3}, {3, 1, 3, 1}, {3, 2, 2, 3}, {3, 2, 3, 2}, {3, 3, 1, 1}, {3, 3, 2, 2}, {3, 3, 4, 4}, {3, 3, 5, 5}, {3, 3, 6, 6}, {3, 4, 3, 4}, {3, 4, 4, 3}, {3, 5, 3, 5}, {3, 5, 5, 3}, {3, 6, 3, 6}, {3, 6, 6, 3}, {4, 1, 1, 4}, {4, 1, 4, 1}, {4, 2, 2, 4}, {4, 2, 4, 2}, {4, 3, 3, 4}, {4, 3, 4, 3}, {4, 4, 1, 1}, {4, 4, 2, 2}, {4, 4, 3, 3}, {4, 4, 5, 5}, {4, 4, 6, 6}, {4, 5, 4, 5}, {4, 5, 5, 4}, {4, 6, 4, 6}, {4, 6, 6, 4}, {5, 1, 1, 5}, {5, 1, 5, 1}, {5, 2, 2, 5}, {5, 2, 5, 2}, {5, 3, 3, 5}, {5, 3, 5, 3}, {5, 4, 4, 5}, {5, 4, 5, 4}, {5, 5, 1, 1}, {5, 5, 2, 2}, {5, 5, 3, 3}, {5, 5, 4, 4}, {5, 5, 6, 6}, {5, 6, 5, 6}, {5, 6, 6, 5}, {6, 1, 1, 6}, {6, 1, 6, 1}, {6, 2, 2, 6}, {6, 2, 6, 2}, {6, 3, 3, 6}, {6, 3, 6, 3}, {6, 4, 4, 6}, {6, 4, 6, 4}, {6, 5, 5, 6}, {6, 5, 6, 5}, {6, 6, 1, 1}, {6, 6, 2, 2}, {6, 6, 3, 3}, {6, 6, 4, 4}, {6, 6, 5, 5}}